# Automated crawling/scraping process output to .txt file using php, javascript or cURL (internal pentest)

Tags: javascript, java, php, python, curl

This is a shot in the dark kind of question where advice and expertise is somewhat a learning curve for a beginner like me, I am looking to run a small internal pentest on an custom coded application.

the url param is like so:  uid=1001 and is consecutive up to uid=380412 as things stand at the moment, what i would like to do is a have a script crawl the site from mysite.com/index.php?uid=1001 to mysite.com/index.php?uid=380412 and save the output file to a consecutive text file so for example there will be a crawled folder names (output) and in there will be text files consecutive to the uid page crawled.

so in the (output) folder 1001.txt will be the output recorded from uid=1001.

i have used cURL commands but as a novice i am unable to automate the process and i dont have the time to site and change every command line uid and text file output for example:

curl --insecure https://removed.com/index.cfm?uid=1001 > eap/1001.txt
and so on until....
curl --insecure https://removed.com/index.cfm?uid=380412 > eap/380412.txt

the reason i am doing this is because i have since found some of the pages to be slightly insecure from an email sent to me by a client and therefore i need to crawl all pages saving the output so i can later inspect the issue.

During the small test i did using the cURL command it was outputting in html, This is not a huge problem, however there is only 1 section in the output file that i am looking into and that is of concern and that is the exposure of customer email addresses, Is it possible to have a script or command crawl the site and if the email address is visible in plaintext then save that file to the .txt file with the exposed email, This will enable me to email the user in question and also implement the correct secure procedures.

**

> So to sum the question up:  i am basically looking for an automated
>   script to crawl the site in question starting from a specific uid and
>   ending at a specific uid by incremental uid numbers, Then save the
>   output to the .txt file matching the uid number. And if possible to
>   only save the .txt file where the email address or an @ sign is
>   present in the html file because the page will only display if there
>   is an email present otherwise the page will display unauthorized
>   access.

**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a code writing request.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

bash for loop should work.

```
for i in {1001..380412}; do
  curl -o eap/$i.txt https://removed.com/index.cfm?uid=$i
done
```

(untested) windows CMD equivalent.

```
FOR /L %G IN (1001,1,380412) DO curl -o eap/%G.txt https://removed.com/index.cfm?uid=%%G
```

Comment: did i get down voted for offering a working solution? didn't seem like he cared about the language and he was already working with a curl cli command

Comment: Thanks for your reply chris, Much appreciated would that auto increment both the uid in the url and the matching .txt file chris? how would i execute the bash on windows?

Comment: btw chris i did not vote you down, someone else must have and to be honest mate its unreasonable because your offering help to someone who has asked a general question. Unacceptable reason for a vote down i believe. Unfortunately as i am new to S.O i dont have the rep to vote you up mate.

Comment: @BirdyUK I added an windows CMD command, it's untested but it or something close to it should work. I don't have a windows box to test on at the moment

Comment: Again thanks for taking time to assist, The following error was displayed: C:\>FOR /L %%G IN (1001,1,383545) DO curl -o --insecure eap/%%G.txt https://....?uid=%%G %%G was unexpected at this time. What would to suggest from there chris?

Comment: try dropping on of the %, %% would be if it was in a batch file. I updated my answer